# What does it mean when words are drawn blue in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here is what I mean:

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/7079/grwb3mmw2gq1bihvt1kb2dn.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/7079/grwb3mmw2gq1bihvt1kb2dn.png)

Sometimes I don't know why, I get the names of functions blue. Is there any special reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a form of syntax coloring and/or spell checking.   It means that a symbol named "SavePlogggts" has not yet been defined.  As soon as you evaluate that cell it will define the symbol and it will turn black.

Answer (score 2):

It just means it's an as-yet-undefined symbol.